# WSO2 api manager - How to display report on "API Usage by Application"

Tags: api, wso2

I am trying to set up wso2 api manager (1.6).

While looking at the reports page, I see there is report for "API usage by user". However, there is always a possibility that same user could be writing multiple applications and may consume the same api across multiple applications (e.g. utility api, authentication service etc)

From my perspective, we need a report for "API usage by application". Is there a way to set it up? or is it possible to customize current report to display this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application associated to each API call is available in WSO2 BAM, you can write a Hive query and generate a report to list 'API usage by application'